# Parsekit equivalent for ABNF construct <any A except B>

Tags: objective-c, parsekit

I want to translate a given ABNF grammar into a valid ParseKit grammar. Actually I'm trying to find a solution for this kind of statement:

```
tag = 1*<any Symbol except "C">
```

with

```
Symbol = "A" / "B" / "C" / "D" // a lot more symbols here...
```

The symbol definition is simplified for this question and normally contains a lot of special characters.
My current solution is to hard code all allowed symbols for `tag`, like

```
tag = ('A' | 'B' | 'D')+;
```

But what I really want is something like a "without operator"

```
tag = Symbol \ 'C';
```

Is there any construct that allows me to keep my symbol list and define some excludes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Developer of [ParseKit](http://parsekit.com) here.

Yes, there is a feature for exactly this. Here's an example:

```
allItems = 'A' | 'B' | 'C' | 'D';
someItems = allItems - 'C';
```

Use the `-` operator.